# Spontaneous muscle twitching?

Tags: brain-development

I am trying to understand the role of whisker twitches during sleep in the development of the mouse brain, and in general the role of spontaneous muscle activity in brain development. Thing is, I am not sure how the muscle activity is initiated. Does the muscle twitch on its own without an electrical input (is this possible?), or does it receive an impulse from the brain to cause it to twitch? I think I read somewhere that the spontaneous activity is generated in the 
brainstem, but I seem to be getting mixed messages...